# Get data from the meta tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read the description from the meta tag and this is what I used

```
soup.findAll(name="description")
```

but it does not work, however, the code below works just fine

```
soup.findAll(align="center")
```

How do I read the description from the meta tag in the head of a document?

Comment: It is unlikely that you found the meta tag contents you wanted by looking for `align="center"`, since align is not really an attribute that makes sense for meta tags, since they're not visible.

Comment: apologies, if my question was confusing. I am not able to find any data when using name="description", but i get data back using align="center"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yep, `name` can't be used in keyword-argument form to designate an attribute named `name` because the name `name` is already used by `BeautifulSoup` itself.  So use instead:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={"name":"description"})
```

That's what the `attrs` argument is **for**: passing as a dict those attribute constraints for which you can't use keyword-argument form because their names are Python keyword or otherwise taken by BeautifulSoup itself!