# Access the 'content' attribute of the 'description' meta tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When [using Beautiful Soup to access a meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774571/get-data-from-the-meta-tags-using-beautifulsoup) the result is presented as the entire tag:

```
soup.find(attrs={"name":"description"})
<meta content="If youre looking for Dotan Cohen, here I am." name="description"/>
```

How might one parse that result to get only the content of the `content` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `.find()` returns an object whose keys you can access.

Try:

```
tag = soup.find(attrs={"name":"description"})
content = tag['content']
```

Note that this returns only the first matching tag. If you need all matching tags, use `.findall()`, which returns a list of tags.

Comment: Here's a link to the specific section in the docs for those interested: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes